# Monitor class with WinRT unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, multithreading, winrt-async

It seems that Monitor doesn't work as expected in WinRT store applications.
I have the following code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select((i)=>new Task(DoWork)).ToArray();
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            task.Start();
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    static object lockObject = new Object();//typeof(MainPage)

    protected async void DoWork()
    {
        bool taken =false;
        Monitor.Enter(lockObject, ref taken);
        Debug.WriteLine("In");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Out");
        if (taken) Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
```

In the output window I see:

```
In
In
In
In
In
In
In
Out
Out
Out
Out
Out
Out
Out
In
Out
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException' occurred in App4.exe
```

Which mean that Monitor is not locking the critical area.
Does anybody has a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're *effectively* trying to use:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

... except that the C# compiler wouldn't allow you to do that, because it would be broken. By the time your `await` expression completes, you can be on a different thread - so when you call `Monitor.Exit`, you may well not be on the same thread as you acquired the lock in... hence the exception.

I suggest that you change your logging to show:

- When you call `In`, what thread you're on and the value of `taken` afterwards (you'll probably see that some tasks *haven't* successfully taken the monitor, because another thread owns it - but see below)
- Before you call `Monitor.Exit`, what thread you're on

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but using `Monitor` here is almost *certainly* the wrong approach.

Also note that because multiple tasks can all execute on the same thread (not at the same time, but you're "giving up" the thread with await) and because monitors are reentrant (one thread can acquire a monitor multiple times) you may well see multiple tasks acquiring the monitor.

It's important that you understand *why* this doesn't work - and that you understand that a thread isn't the same as a task. Then you can try to start working out how to *actually* achieve what you want, which almost certainly isn't via `Monitor`.

Comment: Well, I'm not marking the lockObject as ThreadStatic, so it should be the same object. Even the HashCode within the async method is the same.

Comment: @ikutsin: I never said you were trying to lock against different objects. I said that using `await` between entering a monitor and exiting it is broken.

Comment: @ikutsin Still, you're trying to do what Jon translated to `lock`, and compiler will tell you that 'The 'await' operator cannot be used in the body of a lock statement', which is quite a useful hint. :)

Comment: Basically, I just curious. It is not clear why Monitor behavior is different for async and non async methods.

Comment: @ikutsin: `Monitor` itself behaves exactly the same way - but you need to understand what how async methods behave, and that (depending on the synchronization context) an async method can effectively hop between threads at await expressions.

Comment: Ok then the question why Moninor is just allow to enter the thread. I was expecting the deadlock in UI thread.

Comment: "Also note that because multiple tasks can all execute on the same thread". I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Monitor` doesn't work with `async` methods.

If you want `async`-compatible mutual exclusion, try `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` or [one of the coordination primitives in my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/documentation).